# Naming preference: getSupportedModes() vs supportedModes()?

Tags: naming, getter, preference

I'm having hard time deciding which name to choose for my method. I think they both are pretty much self-explanatory, but the latter is faster to type, so, my current preference is supportedModes(). What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me, `getSupportedModes` implies simple retrieval, whereas if there is some actual logic involved to work them out, something like `determineSupportedModes` or `calculateSupportedModes` may be better. The name should describe what the function does. Brevity is not a major consideration with modern IDEs with some form of autocomplete.

Different languages also have their own conventions. For example, a function called `calculateSupportedModes` in Java would normally be called `CalculateSupportedModes` in C# or VB.

Comment: +1 for the note on autocomplete.  Being a lazy typist is no excuse for poor variable/method naming with a modern auto-completing IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer the more explicit which is getSupportedModes.  You don't want other developers to second guess what the method does.

Answer (score 0):

Functions that act on more than just their passed arguments should be named as actions.

Comment: Not all "functions are actions". Is `sqrt()` an action? Should it be named `CalculateSquareRoot()`? Usually *functions* are not actions, while *methods* usually are.

Comment: An important distinction. Answer clarified.